# react-i18next <Trans> Object is not a valid child

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I'm using react-i18next. And when it comes to `<Trans>` component.

I have something like this:

```js
<Trans i18nKey="showTotal">
   Showing {{total}}
</Trans>
```

```
"showTotal": "Showing {{total}}",
```

But React throws error right away:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {total})

The weird part is my colleague who is using Windows run the code and it's just OK.

Is there anyway I can fix this?

---

**UPDATE**

I used `yarn` to install my packages. It works when I install the packages using `npm` (My colleague is using npm so I try)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use

```
<Interpolate
  i18nKey="showTotal"
  total={111}
/>
```

```
"showTotal": "Showing {{total}}"
```

Result: `Showing 111`